# What services allow you to run a NodeJS App for 1 hour every day?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have a Node task that I run daily, it takes around 1 hour and I'd like to pay for just that hour, rather than having a server run 24/7.

Ideally, it would be something similar to lamda, although Lamda has a limit of 15 mins.

What services allow this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at Heroku - a hobby dyno can cover your needs, you'd just need something to call your service to activate it for a short amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for containerizing your task, you could use a cron schedule on something like ECS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html